# AWS Green Grass Error IncompatibleGccVersion

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, aws-iot-greengrass

Hello Everyone i am running AWS Green Grass on my Raspberry pi 3 Which has Raspbian Installed.
Green grass is installed in the root directory. I have configured AWS Green grass and installed all files and Certificates. i am also able to run AWS Green Grass on Raspberry Pi.

The Problem Comes when i go to AWS Groups and click the deploy button its giving me an error Bad Request Error. error code says IncompatibleGGCVersionException and message says Green grass core version 1.9.4 is below minimum required version 1.10.0

However, there is no 1.10.0 version the latest version is 1.9.4 can someone please help

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Greengrass core 1.10.0 was released on [Nov 25](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2019/11/aws-iot-greengrass-supports-docker-containers-management-data-streams/) and [GGC can be downloaded from here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/greengrass/latest/developerguide/what-is-gg.html#ggc-versions).  Also if a group is created using Easy Group Create, it will add the new stream manager feature by default and this feature requires Java 8 on the Greengrass core device. If you don't want to use the feature, you can go to edit the Group to disable the feature.

Comment: Hello after updating to new green grass core 1.10.0 i am getting following error  Error occured while generating TLS config: unable to decode private key
The Greengrass daemon process with [pid = 18606] died

Comment: Another method to update the Core version is via an Over the Air update. Using the Console go to Sevices -> IoT Core -> Manage -> Jobs -> Create -> Create a Greengass Core Update job